# How to access record properties?

Tags: delphi, record, rtti

I need to access, record properties, and set/get this property values.
Firstly, i want to access properties. But i can't.

What is wrong?
Ver : Delphi XE6.

sample code:

```
type
  TmyRecord = record
  private
    Str : String;
  public
    property StrProp :String read Str;  
  end;


procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 c : TRttiContext;
 t : TRttiType;
 field : TRttiField;
 prop : TRttiProperty;
begin
 c := TRttiContext.Create;
 try
   Memo1.Lines.Append('Fields');
   for field in c.GetType(TypeInfo(TMyRecord)).GetFields do
   begin
     t := field.FieldType;
     Memo1.Lines.Append('Field:'+field.Name);
     Memo1.Lines.Append('RttiType:'+t.ClassName);
   end;

   Memo1.Lines.Append('Properties');
   for prop in c.GetType(TypeInfo(TMyRecord)).GetProperties do
   begin
     t := prop.PropertyType;
     Memo1.Lines.Append('Property:'+prop.Name);
     Memo1.Lines.Append('RttiType:'+t.ClassName);
   end;

 finally
   c.Free
 end;

end;
```

Comment: FWIW, no need to call Free on TRttiContext or even any need to call Create

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no RTTI available for record properties as already reported in 2009 but still not fixed ([QC#78110](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78110)).

**Edit:** And still not fixed in 2017 ([RSP-19303](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19303)).