# Delphi RTTI to iterate properties of Generic record type

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

I have several classes with properties of simple types (Integer, Boolean, string) and some Nullable's:

```
  Nullable<T> = record
  private
    FValue: T;
    FHasValue: IInterface;
    function GetValue: T;
    function GetHasValue: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(AValue: T);
    property HasValue: Boolean read GetHasValue;
    property Value: T read GetValue;
  end;
```

Eg.

```
  TMyClass1 = class(TCommonAncestor)
    private
      FNumericvalue: Double;
      FEventTime: Nullable<TDateTime>;
    public 
      property NumericValue: Double read FNumericValue write FNumericValue;
      property EventTime: Nullable<TDateTime> read FEventTime write FEventTime;   
  end;
```

and

```
  TMyClass2 = class(TCommonAncestor)
    private
      FCount: Nullable<Integer>;
      FName: string;
    public 
      property Count: Nullable<Integer> read FCount write FCount;
      property Name: string read FName write FName;   
  end;
```

etc....

Given a descendant of TCommonAncestor, I would like to use RTTI to iterate all public properties and list their name and value, unless it is a Nullable where T.HasValue returns false.

I am using Delphi XE2.

**EDIT: added what I have so far.**

```
procedure ExtractValues(Item: TCommonAncestor);
var
  c : TRttiContext;
  t : TRttiType;
  p : TRttiProperty;
begin
  c := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    t := c.GetType(Item.ClassType);
    for p in t.GetProperties do
    begin
      case p.PropertyType.TypeKind of
        tkInteger:
          OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('%se=%s', [p.Name,p.GetValue(Item).ToString]));
        tkRecord:
        begin
          // for Nullable<Double> p.PropertyType.Name contains 'Nullable<System.Double>'
          // but how do I go about accessing properties of this record-type field?
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to solve this? Public properties are not accessible via legacy RTTI (the `System.TypInfo` unit) so you have to use Extended RTTI (the `System.Rtti` unit)

Comment: I have modified my question to show that I am trying to use System.Rtti

Comment: Accessing record properties with RTTI is not possible. You would have to go for the record fields instead.

Comment: @LU RD can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @LURD: That is not true. Record properties can be accessed via Extended RTTI. I just tried it and it worked fine.  It just takes a little trickery to access the actual `Nullable` object. I'll write up an answer shortly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ok so this is not valid then? [How to access record properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450935/576719). *"Your problem is that there is no RTTI available for record properties as already reported in 2009 but still not fixed"*

Comment: @TheRoadRunner, Unless I'm misinformed (as Remy states), you would have to access the nullable fields directly. I just tried, no problem. See my contribution here: [Convert Record to Serialized Form Data for sending via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514088/576719), where record and classed are serialized with RTTI. I just added a line for the tkInterface type: `sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' + thing.ToString);` I'm sure you can work it out from there, if not Remy figures out another way.

Comment: Here is the printout from a fake initialized class: `object tCl1:TMyClass1
  FNumericvalue:Double=42
  record FEventTime:Nullable<System.TDateTime>
    FValue:TDateTime=2017-10-19 22:05:35
    FHasValue:IInterface=(empty)
  end
end
`

Comment: @LURD: [How to access record properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450935/576719) asks how to access properties that are inside of a record type, which indeed does not work due to lack of RTTI for a record's properties. But that is not what this question is about. This question is asking how to access a property that is a record type, and that works just fine with RTTI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me in XE2:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo, System.Rtti, System.StrUtils, Winapi.Windows;

type
  Nullable<T> = record
  private
    FValue: T;
    FHasValue: IInterface;
    function GetHasValue: Boolean;
    function GetValue: T;
    procedure SetValue(const AValue: T);
  public
    constructor Create(AValue: T);
    function ToString: string; // <-- add this for easier use!
    property HasValue: Boolean read GetHasValue;
    property Value: T read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TCommonAncestor = class
  end;

  TMyClass1 = class(TCommonAncestor)
  private
    FNumericvalue: Double;
    FEventTime: Nullable<TDateTime>;
  public
    property NumericValue: Double read FNumericValue write FNumericValue;
    property EventTime: Nullable<TDateTime> read FEventTime write FEventTime;
  end;

  TMyClass2 = class(TCommonAncestor)
  private
    FCount: Nullable<Integer>;
    FName: string;
  public
    property Count: Nullable<Integer> read FCount write FCount;
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
  end;

...

constructor Nullable<T>.Create(AValue: T);
begin
  SetValue(AValue);
end;

function Nullable<T>.GetHasValue: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FHasValue <> nil;
end;

function Nullable<T>.GetValue: T;
begin
  if HasValue then
    Result := FValue
  else
    Result := Default(T);
end;

procedure Nullable<T>.SetValue(const AValue: T);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  FHasValue := TInterfacedObject.Create;
end;

function Nullable<T>.ToString: string;
begin
  if HasValue then
  begin
    // TValue.ToString() does not output T(Date|Time) values as date/time strings,
    // it outputs them as floating-point numbers instead, so do it manually...
    if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TDateTime) then
      Result := DateTimeToStr(PDateTime(@FValue)^)
    else if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TDate) then
      Result := DateToStr(PDateTime(@FValue)^)
    else if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TTime) then
      Result := TimeToStr(PDateTime(@FValue)^)
    else
      Result := TValue.From<T>(FValue).ToString;
  end
  else
    Result := '(null)';
end;

procedure ExtractValues(Item: TCommonAncestor);
var
  c : TRttiContext;
  t : TRttiType;
  p : TRttiProperty;
  v : TValue;
  m : TRttiMethod;
  s : string;
begin
  c := TRttiContext.Create;

  t := c.GetType(Item.ClassType);
  for p in t.GetProperties do
  begin
    case p.PropertyType.TypeKind of
      tkRecord:
      begin
        if StartsText('Nullable<', p.PropertyType.Name) then
        begin
          // get Nullable<T> instance...
          v := p.GetValue(Item);
          // invoke Nullable<T>.ToString() method on that instance...
          m := c.GetType(v.TypeInfo).GetMethod('ToString');
          s := m.Invoke(v, []).AsString;
        end else
          s := Format('(record type %s)', [p.PropertyName.Name]);
      end;
    else
      s := p.GetValue(Item).ToString;
    end;
    OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('%s=%s', [p.Name, s])))
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  Item1: TMyClass1;
  Item2: TMyClass2;
begin
  Item1 := TMyClass1.Create;
  try
    Item1.NumericValue := 123.45;
    Item1.EventTime.SetValue(Now);
    ExtractValues(Item1);
    { Output: 
      NumericValue=123.45
      EventTime=10/19/2017 1:25:05 PM
    }
  finally
    Item1.Free;
  end;

  Item1 := TMyClass1.Create;
  try
    Item1.NumericValue := 456.78;
    //Item1.EventTime.SetValue(Now);
    ExtractValues(Item1);
    { Output: 
      NumericValue=456.78
      EventTime=(null)
    }
  finally
    Item1.Free;
  end;

  Item2 := TMyClass2.Create;
  try
    Item2.Count.SetValue(12345);
    Item2.Name := 'test';
    ExtractValues(Item2);
    { Output: 
      Count=12345
      Name=test
    }
  finally
    Item2.Free;
  end;

  Item2 := TMyClass2.Create;
  try
    //Item2.Count.SetValue(12345);
    Item2.Name := 'test2';
    ExtractValues(Item2);
    { Output: 
      Count=(null)
      Name=test2
    }
  finally
    Item2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Remy Excellent solution, thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: Hello @Remy wonderful solution, but what about SetValue of a nullable ? if  i make a question here, do you answer it for me ?

Comment: @Rebelss what about `SetValue()` exactly? What is your question?

Comment: @Remi here, i've tried to put it in form of a question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704576/setting-a-value-in-a-nullablet-record-with-rtti